# Spring Cloud Function GCP exclude for Spring Cloud Stream for PubSub

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-function, spring-cloud-gcp

I combine both Spring Cloud Function for GCP and Spring Cloud Stream for PubSub in the same project.
I have one function which is an entrypoint for GCP CF defined in my properties
`spring.cloud.function.definition=gcpFunction`

I bridge the result of the function with Spring Cloud Stream binding by StreamBridge.

Unexpectedly Spring Cloud Stream also automatically binds the `gcpFunction` function and creates an unwanted topic in PubSub. I would like to exclude the function from the automatic binding for Spring Cloud Stream.
The only workaround I found is to bind Spring Cloud Function explicitly to none existing function e.g. `spring.cloud.stream.function.definition=doNotBindFunction`

This is not ideal because Spring during startup prints some warnings about a missing function and also looks a bit hacky.
Is there any other recommended solution?

I looked at the following topics but seems like they don't really solve many problem [Is it possible to disable spring-cloud-stream's functional binding for a specific method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59181853/is-it-possible-to-disable-spring-cloud-streams-functional-binding-for-a-specifi)
as @SpringBootApplication(exclude = ContextFunctionCatalogAutoConfiguration.class) disables also configuration for my `gcpFunction`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `spring.cloud.stream.function.autodetect=false`. This will turn off autodiscovery of functional beans ([refdoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.2.2/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring_cloud_function)).

Comment: I tried, and it did not work. I think this flag does not help if you have defined `spring.cloud.function.definition`  But if I don't define this property Spring would not bind my function to GCP adapter.

Comment: From my understanding when I have defined `spring.cloud.stream.function.definition` it would activate org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.FunctionConfiguration which takes priority on function discovery.
Otherwise it uses somewhere some defaults which take probably whatever is visible in function catalogue via "spring.cloud.function.definition"

Comment: You can see right here https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/blob/b4c6ec8332c73ca62b14bb8ad7b1cbbd0644e411/core/spring-cloud-stream/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/function/FunctionConfiguration.java#L978

The definition is taken from "spring.cloud.function.definition" and autodetect flag would just prevent find anything (I guess `functionCatalog.lookup("")`) in the function catalogue
`"spring.cloud.function.definition"` is a default when no `spring.cloud.stream.function.definition` is defined which is not a good default in my case

Comment: I could possibly register the GCP function on my own programmatically e.g via Bean Definitions and delete spring.cloud.function.definition and set spring.cloud.stream.function.autodetect=false this migth work...

Comment: Sounds like a good feature request for Spring Cloud Stream.